# The curious case of numerical phase plot of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Consider the following numerical phase plot of a two-dimensional system of ordinary differential equations.

[image]

This system was plotted for a relative error tolerance of $10^{-4}$. For tighter tolerances in relative error the phase plot doesn't change, so we can assume that this is a good approximation of the phase plot of the true solution orbit.

The problem, that I don't understand is: If I redo the plot for bigger tolerances, i.e. greater than $10^{-3}$, surprisingly I obtain again a spiral picture.

[image]

But for a tolerance $1.1 \cdot 10^{-3}$ I find that the system again looks similar to the one at the top, for tolerance $10^{-4}$. This figure shows that (plottet with tolerance $1.1 \cdot 10^{-3}$):

[image]

*How can this happen, that for a worse relative error tolerance, my plot suddenly looks better? What qualitative causes could be for such a behavior?*

But it gets even weirder: If I increase the tolerance more, to $1.2 \cdot 10^{-3}$ I still have a spiral-like picture (although the spiral gets uglier and uglier), but $1.3 \cdot 10^{-3}$, the system again looks like a tail picture! Then for $1.4 \cdot 10^{-3}$ we again have a spiral picture, for $1.5 \cdot 10^{-3}$ again a tail picture, for $1.6 \cdot 10^{-3}$ again a spiral picture and for $1.7 \cdot 10^{-3}$ onwards again a tail picture. How can this "oscillating" behavior happen ?

[Here's](https://gofile.io/?c=7t9rs9) the MATLAB code for those persistent enough and with a desire to reproduce the figures above.

```
function dotY = f(t,Y)
  Y100 = Y.^100
  H = Y100./(1+Y100)
  dotY = [ H(1)+H(2)-2*H(1)*H(2)-0.6*Y(1) ; 1-H(1)*H(2)-0.9*Y(2) ]
end
```

Comment: Can you include the system in the question for those of us who do not use MatLab?

Comment: Your system has an approximate jump of size 1 when one of the coordinates passes the value 1. This is stiff behavior. Explicit methods as ode45 are not very good at regions of stiffness, essentially behaving randomly in how it passes that region. Use implicit solvers to get a little more predictability.

Comment: @LutzL Hmm, good point. But is this the only possible source for the shown behavior? I remember when I created those figure to also have tried other solvers (but I'm not sure) with similar effect. If you could go a bit into the reason why solvers that are not designed for stiff  regions go rogue in those regions, and post that as an answer, I could accept it. (Also, what is stiffness? Wikipedia says "the main idea is that the equation includes some terms that can lead to rapid variation in the solution", but that is not a precise definition. Isn't it possible, at least in my example, [...]

Comment: [...] that the equation is non-stiff as up to some power $n<100$ and stiff afterwards? Please note that I do not know much about numerics.)